# How can I thank or apologize to another user?

Tags: support

I'm a native English speaker, I enjoy the World Building SE, posting answers and helping questioners when I can; however, I regularly have my answers edited by other users.

**This is definitely not a problem**, quite the opposite in fact, because it appears I am truly terrible at noticing spelling and grammar mistakes, my most recent one was edited by Renan [Humans returning to tribalism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/126388/humans-returning-to-tribalism/126403#126403)

Looking at the edits he's made it must have taken him some time and he's not the only one, I'm sure several people reading this post will have edited an answer or two of mine.

I do proof read my answers but somehow miss these mistakes. this means others end up editing my answers and correcting those mistakes

Is there any way (other than editing my answers saying thank you to the editor) I can apologize to everyone for my bad spelling and grammar and thank those that take the time to edit them?

PS: I took a long time to type this very short post, to make sure I didn't spell anything wrong, please forgive me if I did...

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate that you'd like to reward editors for their effort, but the site already does that for you. The mechanics of Stack Echange gamify maintainance activities :)

[image: Sysiphus!]
(From [SMBC](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2014-02-05))

In my case I am going after the [copy editor badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor), and I am not even halfway there.

Best thing about this is that after you do something for a while, it becomes a habit. For example, most users I see posting often have the electorate badge (vote on 600+ questions, and a quarter of all your votes must be on questions), and though there is no further reward for it, we keep voting. Just the same, I will keep editing after I get the badge.

Asides from badges, participation is already rewarding in itself. More than badges, I do stuff because I find it fun to do.

Comment: How have I never seen that comic before.  Its beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

Typos and misspellings happen. I often find myself missing some -s in the third person, or even worse, when I type something.

One of the community tasks is also editing text and fixing errors, and it is a task that can also award badge and reputation.

Therefore I would say that you don't need to explicitly thank whoever reviewed your posts. If you are putting effort into proofreading your posts you are already doing something to mitigate the issue. If you want to thank the community for what it does for you, do something for the community, like you are already doing:

> I enjoy worldBuilding.SE, posting answers and helping questioners when I can

P.S. Quite ironically, you slipped a small typo in your question, despite your best effort. I edited it out. It happens, no bad feelings about it.

Answer (score 3):

I often drop a comment to thank people who clean up my posts, especially when they've had to do a lot of work. You could also drop a tagged comment into the chat as well.